# Usage of nashorn javascript enigne along with jdk 1.6

Tags: javascript, rhino, nashorn, jsr223, javascript-engine

My code is using rhino javascript engine in jdk 1.6/jdk 1.8 (with external rhino jars). Is there anyway I can implement nashorn javascript engine in jdk 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

No. Nashorn uses invokedynamic which implies that you've to be on jdk7 at the minimum. Also I think jdk 8 Java constructs are used in the nashorn code - which implies that you've to be on jdk8+.